# Inverse Galois problem on the upper or lower numbering filtration

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, ramification

Let $K$ be a (complete) discrete valuated field and $E$ a Galois extension of group $G$. Then one has two filtrations on $G$, the upper and the lower numbering.

Assume that $K$ is equal to its maximal tame extension (that is, forget about the $0$-th part of these filtrations) and that the residue field of $
K$ has characteristic $p>0$, then my questions are: if one fixes $G$ a $p$-group and an arbitrary filtration $G_i$ of normal subgroups (possibly with $G_i=G_{i+1}$ for some $i$) with $G_i/G_{i+1}$ abelian, is there $K$ and $E$ as before such that this is the lower numbering filtration of $E/K$? What about the upper?

Are there further restrictions that ensure such an existence?

Answer (score 4):

It is not sufficient to require that the quotients $G_i/G_{i+1}$ be commutative; they also have to have exponent dividing $p$.  There are further restrictions, and the question has been studied by Maus in particular.

See for example

Eckart Maus,
*Die gruppentheoretische Struktur der Verzweigungsgruppenreihen,*
Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik (1968)
Volume: 230, page 1-28
https://eudml.org/doc/150845

Review : http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=225763

Here is a summary in English :

Eckart Maus,
*On the jumps in the series of ramifications groups,*
Mémoires de la Société Mathématique de France (1971)
Volume: 25, page 127-133
https://eudml.org/doc/94571

Review : http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=364194